# Как оправить изображение в форму используя Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, изображения, input

Исходный код страницы:

```html
<div elementsid="saddimages" class="item images tooltip upload dropZone" title="Прикрепить изображения"><div class="fileUploader"><div class="elContent"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> <span class="mobiledevice">Прикрепить изображения</span></div><div class="spinner"></div><div class="inputWrapper"><input elementsid="fileuploader_input" type="file" multiple=""></div></div></div>
```

Страница создания статьи в Bastyon : https://bastyon.com/(mypage)

Пытаюсь использовать вот такую комбинацию. В итоге ошибка. При физическом нажатии на кнопку появляется окно для добавления файла. Помогите...

Мой код:

```
image_path = r"/home/my/Desktop/b50dd6b1ebc7e97c3e5fe2d9e85f9a7a.jpg" 
    file_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@elementsid="fileuploader_input"]')))
    file_input.send_keys(image_path)
```

**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**